# MediatR - avoid early validation or unnecessary service registrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, clean-architecture, mediatr

I have an architecture with the following libraries, apis

`Presentation`
`Application`
`Core`
`SharedKernel`
`SecurityWeb API`
`Main Web API`
`Infrastructure`

The `Application` layer contains all query handlers.

And from the `Main and Security` web app, we register application services.

But when Running `Security Web API` independently it forces me to register the `Main Web API` specific services which I do not need to register for `Security WEB Api` stuff.

I've spent a bunch of hours over that and before making major changes, I wanted to get an idea of you beforehand.

`Security Web API` sends the following code result to MediatR

```
Assembly[] GetProjectAssemblies()
{
    var coreAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Proj.Core.DependencyConfigurator));

    var appAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Proj.Application.DependencyConfigurator));

    var webApiAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    var requiredAssemblies = new[] { appAssembly, coreAssembly, webApiAssembly };

    return requiredAssemblies;
}
```

And the `Main WEB API` sends the following code result to MediatR

```
Assembly[] GetProjectAssemblies()
{
    var coreAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Proj.Core.DependencyConfigurator));
    Guard.Against.Null(coreAssembly);

    var appAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Proj.Application.DependencyConfigurator));
    Guard.Against.Null(appAssembly);

    var kernelProject = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Proj.SharedKernel.DomainEventBase)); // Any type does the trick
    Guard.Against.Null(kernelProject);

    var infraAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Proj.Infrastructure.DependencyConfigurator));
    Guard.Against.Null(infraAssembly);

    var webApiAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AssetProvider));
    Guard.Against.Null(webApiAssembly);

    var requiredAssemblies = new[] { appAssembly, infraAssembly, kernelProject, coreAssembly, webApiAssembly };
    return requiredAssemblies;
}
```